# Lost Network Interface Virtualbox on Win7

Tags: windows, virtualbox, nat, bridge

Yesterday I have installed Virtualbox on my win7 notebook and i have seen, that VB have install a network interface on the win7 network properties.

After installing Ubuntu guest on a new VB-instance, ubuntu cannot connect to the internet. Later into the night i have read somewhere that i should deactivate the network-interface and re-activate it.

So, i have deactivate this network-interface on win7 and after that, i have lost this and cannot re-activate it. The VB-Guest cannot connect now over bridget and so on.

How i get the network interface back into win7 for working the vb guest over bridge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Open **device manager**
2) Under **Network interfaces**
You will find your lost adapter.
3) Right click it and click enable.

Comment: Ok, thanks.. now i have the adapter into the network interfaces, but the ubuntu guest still not get the connection. A ping will not work. My normally wlan have 192.168.1.118 on the gateway 192.168.1.1, but the vbox network adapter goes to 192.168.56.1 without gateway and dns. I think here are the problem, but i'm not sure?